# Rails validating phone number regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

Trying to strengthen my user profile forms etc by adding effective regex's to ensure that valid emails, phone numbers etc are being used.
I have the following regex, that works fine when tested on Rubular, however I get a syntax error when I add it to my model as below:

```
(^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$

validates_format_of :contactnr, with: (^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$, allow_blank => true
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the closing bracket `)` before the end of line `$`

Try this:

```
(^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})$
```

Take a look at this [link](http://regexlib.com/%28X%281%29A%28WWkg9hxEwnTOWaqN6xO4MVhphDucEYS_sEa7qAGNWYlf3ZUiV0GoNVICkvGv7ELAX7ZbWFaOjS_RSDgY424dHPzM4E6y9sUNUsnJ9WptG6QfPhrMm2_PJOtMzWQ4d7e_BQcsHx8Q6p7SrAiltEoVOs5brsAhrq0E2PT5NikaOp0-tkCjVMbFsdfVsnTJ4M2Y0%29%29/UserPatterns.aspx?authorid=d95177b0-6014-4e73-a959-73f1663ae814&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), There are some UK phone number regular expressions there.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's literal regex is enclosed in `//`:

```
validates_format_of :contactnr, with: /^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/, allow_blank => true
```

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html):

> A `Regexp` holds a regular expression, used to match a pattern against
>   strings. Regexps are created using the `/.../` and `%r{...}` literals, and
>   by the `Regexp::new` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Both @Uri and @Pedro ad good points as to missing syntax and correctly wrapping the regex.
Another issue I cam across once that was fixed was that the 'allow_blank' method needs to be a symbol. Working code below.

```
validates_format_of :contactnr, with: /\A((\(?0\d{4}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|(\(?0\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|(\(?0\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?\Z/, :allow_blank => true
```